# Unit test with Gmock fundamentals: Dealing with function parameter defined in another namespace

Tags: unit-testing, googlemock

I have been trying hard but could not search any relevant help from online resources. Being new to UT, thus I guess my best choice is to ask here directly. If you do not have direct answer, any relevant resource link is also much appreciated.

My problems sound like this:

```
//My environment is in C++
//The below code snippet is for reader to understand why I encounter build errors and how should I resolve

//Source code .cpp file (target to run UT on)
class realChild : public virtualParent
{
public:
  bool member_func (const OtherNamespace::CustomizedParams &sParams,
                    int other_Params,
                    char other_Params2) const;
}

//Header .h file - the class interface
class virtualParent
{
  virtual bool member_func (const OtherNamespace::CustomizedParams &sParams,
                    int other_Params,
                    char other_Params2) const = 0;
}


//UT .cpp file - the place that I wanted to mock the class to perform unit test
#include "OtherNamespace.h"
using OtherNamespace
class MockrealChild : public virtualParent
{
public:
  MOCK_METHOD3(member_func, bool(const CustomizedParams, int, char));
}
```

Ended up with build errors like this, where I could not find any constructive suggestion to overcome.

error: forward declaration of 'OtherNamespace::CustomizedParams'

Comment: Your function is declared as a const, but you're mocking regular method. Try using const MOCK_CONST_METHOD3() instead of MOCK_METHOD3.

Comment: Moreover, first  parameter type of member_func is a reference, but your mock signature states it's a value.